# Will Careers be of use to contractors?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I'll probably get in on the $29.00 deal on Careers even though I'm not a developer by trade (I'm an IT / network / server guy-- you may have seen me on Server Fault  >smile<) and even though I'm not looking for a "job". Buying a listing lets me support Jeff and Joel's fun little venture here, and makes me feel good.

I don't want a "job" from an "employer" ever again. I like being an independent contractor a *lot*. Five years of this lifestyle has completely ruined me for ever having a "job" again.

So, having said that, is it anywhere in the design goals for careers.stackoverflow.com to offer specific features that are of help to those people who, like me, aren't looking for jobs but rather are looking for contracting opportunities?

Edit:

I saw that there was an option to specify "Temporary contract" under the "What type of work are you seeking?" heading, so that fulfills my "contractor seeking contracts" need.

What about the "employer" (contractee?) looking for a contractor? I see Jeff talking about marketing to "hiring managers", but typically "hiring managers" aren't the people who end up looking for contractors (at least in my experience). Will there be marketing / access opportunities for the various "non-hiring manager" manangers who might want to find contractors?

Comment: Evan, I'm also interested in this, and I've thought up the following which might be useful to contractors for both programming and IT. What do you think?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31896/are-developers-interested-in-community-development-on-commercial-projects

Answer (score 2):

There's a "*Temporary contract*" checkbox among the options under the "*What type of work are you seeking?*" heading that would seem to fit the bill...